# Why is the dimen resource inconsistent and how to get the correct value?

Tags: java, android, android-xml, text-size

I was writing an Android app. I basically created the following `dimen` resource:

```
<dimen name="button_text_size">11pt</dimen>
```

And I use it in both my xml and Java code to create a `Button` and a `TextView` which text size is 11pt. Here is how I did this:

XML

```
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:textSize="@dimen/button_text_size"
        android:text="secret!"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/button_margin"
        android:background="secret!"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="secret!"/>
```

Java code

```
TextView text = new TextView (this);
        text.setLayoutParams (new LinearLayout.LayoutParams (0, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 3));
        text.setText (secret);
        text.setTextSize (getResources().getDimension (R.dimen.button_text_size));
```

In theory, the text of the two views should be the same size. But the text view's text size appears to be larger! I don't know why this is happening. I guess it is because of some problems with the units but what is actually happening? How to get the *correct* values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX,getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.button_text_size));
```

and it better to use sp( "scaled pixel") as text size as per android documentation 
http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/widget/Button.html

Comment: Just one more question, if I use sp, am I able to use the method in my question? I mean the setTextSize(float) overload.

Comment: yes you can use setTextSize method , or you want to ask anything else?

Answer (score 1):

Use `dp or dip`   instead of `pt`

```
 <dimen name="button_text_size">11dp</dimen>
```

Comment: Although I don't know much about the units, I am sure dp is not equal to pt. Can I still keep using pt?

Comment: @Sweeper For better approach You switch to use `dp`

Comment: http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:textSize

Answer (score 0):

> dp/dip: Density-independent Pixels - An abstract unit that is based on the
> physical density of the screen. These units are relative to a 160 dpi
> (dots per inch) screen, on which 1dp is roughly equal to 1px. When
> running on a higher density screen, the number of pixels used to draw
> 1dp is scaled up by a factor appropriate for the screen's dpi.
> Likewise, when on a lower density screen, the number of pixels used
> for 1dp is scaled down.

**On the other hand**

> pt:Points - 1/72 of an inch based on the physical size of the screen.

> px: Pixels - Corresponds to actual pixels on the screen. This unit of
> measure is not recommended because the actual representation can vary
> across devices;

So **pt and px will vary screen to screen** while dp**/dip will manage according to the screen.**..if you want consistent size across different screen than go for dp/dip

For more on DIMENSIONS [refer](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension)

 Therefore change from 11pt to 11dp in XML this will help

 But dynamically it considered as floating value in terms of px...so go for solution provide by pavan as in

```
textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX,getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.button_text_size));
```

**Either go for one of the below values.**

```
textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.button_text_size));

textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.button_text_size));
```